# In maven how to set a timeout for each repository in settings.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

My Settings.xml has multiple repositories. I would like to set a custom timeout for each repository.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Do you have "unreliable" repositories? How do you plan to handle if one is not available?

Comment: I have a repository which is unreliable and I do not have a alternate repository as well. So, even if the build is going to fail, maven takes a lot of time to even realise that a particular artifactory is not found/ available

Comment: What about establishing your own repository which proxies the relevant repositories? Nexus, for example, is easy to install and handle. Then most of your reliability issues should be gone.

Comment: Thanks Meier. I will use that as my plan B. But is it not possible to set a timeout at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured the problem. I was running the maven build inside a docker container. My corporate network was behind a proxy and this proxy was not able to forward requests internally which caused the problem.

So, basically there was no delay from the maven's point of view. It is just that maven was not able to reach the repo from inside the docker.

To conclude it was a network issue.